# Is there a way to bind with DN using django-python3-ldap

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ldap

Because there are some AD migrations coming up in our organization, I want to find the user using a specific field and binding with the corresponding DN rather than the sAMAccountName or userPrincipalName in our Django environment.

When reading the [django-python3-ldap](https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap) docs I couldn't find if the package supports this. Is this true? Should I try to use another package that does supports this?